# How to compare a value to be within one of several ranges using a PIC16F877A

Tags: assembly, embedded, pic, mplab

Homework Problem: Keep everything the same as in Homework #1, design a system that can read the potentiometer’s settings and display the real-time voltage ranges of High, Medium, and Low on the LCD module.
  Your program should display the real-time voltage of High=4.5 V and above, Medium=between 2.0V and 3.0V, and Low=1.5V and below and update the reading and display every 5 seconds to reflect the changes on the potentiometer. If the voltage in not in the ranges, then display “Unknown” on the LCD.

I've gotten the ASM to do everything but to be able to do "greater than," "less than," for the ranges. I can see how to do this in C-code for the PIC, but not in ASM. Any help would be appreciated.

Board: uC Training System Manual Rev. 3 from ODU
Microchip: PIC16F877A 
Coding Language: ASM within MPLAB (MPASM Assembler v5.50)

Simplified test code focused on just range comparison:

```
; 
; File: main.asm
; Target: PIC16F877A
; 
; Description:
;   Simplified range compare test code
; 
    #include <P16F877A.INC>


    __CONFIG  0x3F32                ;This is the control bits for CONFIG register

    ORG     0x0000                  ;RESET or WDT reset vector
    GOTO    START

    ORG     0x0004                  ;Regular INT vector

;This is the area where your interrupt service routine goes

    RETFIE
;
;Table of messages
;
Message_High:
    DT "High"
Message_Mid:
    DT "Mid"
Message_Low:
    DT "Low"
Message_Unknown:
    DT "Unknown"

ValueToCheck EQU    0x20

START:                              ;The starting place of the user codes

    banksel ValueToCheck
    clrf    ValueToCheck

TestLoop:
    movf    ValueToCheck,W
    sublw   d'45'                   ; Do calculation: WREG - ValueToCheck
    btfsc   STATUS,C                ; CARRY not set so ValueToCheck < 45
    goto    ShowHigh

    movf    ValueToCheck,W
    sublw   d'30'                   ; Do calculation: WREG - ValueToCheck
    btfsc   STATUS,C                ; CARRY not set so ValueToCheck < 30
    goto    ShowUnknown

    movf    ValueToCheck,W
    sublw   d'20'                   ; Do calculation: WREG - ValueToCheck
    btfsc   STATUS,C                ; CARRY not set so ValueToCheck < 20
    goto    ShowMid

    movf    ValueToCheck,W
    sublw   d'15'                   ; Do calculation: WREG - ValueToCheck
    btfsc   STATUS,C                ; CARRY not set so ValueToCheck < 15
    goto    ShowUnknown

ShowLow:
    movlw   Message_Low             ; Load WREG with message pointer
    goto    ShowMessage

ShowMid:
    movlw   Message_Mid             ; Load WREG with message pointer
    goto    ShowMessage

ShowHigh:
    movlw   Message_High            ; Load WREG with message pointer
    goto    ShowMessage

ShowUnknown:
    movlw   Message_Unknown         ; Load WREG with message pointer
ShowMessage:
;
; This is test code so no output
;
    nop     ; With breakpoint here. WREG not loaded with expected message pointer.
;
;
;
    incf    ValueToCheck,F
    goto    TestLoop

    END                             ;End program
```

I just need help figuring out how to get the program to display the voltage in RANGES in the ASM to the LCD. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt, with emphasis on the minimal part.

Comment: The moderators have placed this topic on hold. The post seems to be asking for one thing. That is how to code a relation test of an integer value in assembly language for a PIC16F877A controller from Microchip.

Comment: @Dan1138: Your edits are a big improvement.  Now it's not "too broad" anymore.  But now it might be missing a [mcve]; the code with a chain of 4 branches that are supposed to implement `if(x>45) goto somewhere` and so on look like the right idea (I don't know PIC specifically, so they might be doing it wrong.  But the comments look sensible.)  If this doesn't work, we need info on what actually does happen for this debugging question to be on-topic.  Maybe someone with expertise in the PIC tag could comment on whether this is ready for reopening, or if it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Peter: I now know what is wrong with the test code in the question. To explain it using comments does not seem practical. I can post an answer if this topic is ever opened.

Comment: @Dan1138: Ok, I voted to reopen.  This kind of debugging question tends to have very low future value, at least as far as explanation of the actual bug, because people don't know what their bug is and can't search for this.  It might be useful for people that want the one-of-4-ranges chain of branches like the title says.

Comment: @ Peter: Thanks for trying but from what I understand it will take at lest 4 or 5 more votes to reopen this topic without some action from a moderator. As for anyone searching for relational compare code for a PIC controller in assembly language. I do not see people new to PIC coding putting that query together.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to thank Peter Cordes for getting this topic reopened. We will see if my answer was worth it.

Doing a relational compare with the PIC16F877A in assembly language presents issues for the new kids. Here are things I found confusing.

The PIC16F does not do signed arithmetic.

The subtract instruction indicates a BORROW by asserting a NOT CARRY.

The opcode 'SUBLW' confused me about the order of subtraction.

From the data sheet I found that the CARRY and ZERO flags are the result of: (k - WREG) for a literal constant 'k'.

The relationship between the literal constant 'k' and the WREG after a "SUBLW k" statement is indicated in the status flags as:

- ZERO is set,   CARRY is set   when 'k' = WREG
- ZERO is clear, CARRY is set   when 'k' > WREG
- ZERO is clear, CARRY is clear when 'k' < WREG

With this clearer description of how the status flags behave the working code looks like this:

```
; 
; File: main.asm
; Target: PIC16F877A
; 
; Description:
;   Simplified range compare test code
;
;   Bugs corrected 2019-NOV-05
; 
    #include <P16F877A.INC>


    __CONFIG  0x3F32                ;This is the control bits for CONFIG register

    ORG     0x0000                  ;RESET or WDT reset vector
    GOTO    START

    ORG     0x0004                  ;Regular INT vector

;This is the area where your interrupt service routine goes

    RETFIE
;
;Table of messages
;
Message_High:
    DT "High"
Message_Mid:
    DT "Mid"
Message_Low:
    DT "Low"
Message_Unknown:
    DT "Unknown"

ValueToCheck EQU    0x20

START:                              ;The starting place of the user codes

    banksel ValueToCheck
    clrf    ValueToCheck

TestLoop:
    movf    ValueToCheck,W
    sublw   d'45'                   ; Do calculation: 45 - ValueToCheck
    btfss   STATUS,Z                ; ZERO  set so ValueToCheck = 45
    btfss   STATUS,C                ; CARRY set so ValueToCheck < 45
    goto    ShowHigh                ; When ValueToCheck >= 45

    movf    ValueToCheck,W
    sublw   d'30'                   ; Do calculation: 30 - ValueToCheck
    btfss   STATUS,C                ; CARRY set so ValueToCheck < 30
    goto    ShowUnknown             ; When 30 > ValueToCheck < 45

    movf    ValueToCheck,W
    sublw   d'20'                   ; Do calculation: 20 - ValueToCheck
    btfss   STATUS,Z                ; ZERO  set so ValueToCheck = 20
    btfss   STATUS,C                ; CARRY set so ValueToCheck < 20
    goto    ShowMid                 ; When 20 >= ValueToCheck <= 30

    movf    ValueToCheck,W
    sublw   d'15'                   ; Do calculation: 15 - ValueToCheck
    btfss   STATUS,C                ; CARRY set so ValueToCheck <= 15
    goto    ShowUnknown             ; When 15 > ValueToCheck < 20

ShowLow:                            ; When ValueToCheck <= 15
    movlw   Message_Low             ; Load WREG with message pointer
    goto    ShowMessage

ShowMid:
    movlw   Message_Mid             ; Load WREG with message pointer
    goto    ShowMessage

ShowHigh:
    movlw   Message_High            ; Load WREG with message pointer
    goto    ShowMessage

ShowUnknown:
    movlw   Message_Unknown         ; Load WREG with message pointer
ShowMessage:
;
; This is test code so no output
;
    nop     ; With breakpoint here. WREG now loaded with expected message pointer.
;
;
;
    incf    ValueToCheck,F
    goto    TestLoop

    END                             ;End program
```

Comment: Can you do `sublw d'21'` or `19` instead so you don't need to branch separately on `==` and `<`?

Comment: @Peter, You are correct, though that is just one of the kinds of optimizations that students learning to code in assembly language should be allowed to discover. There are several solutions for this kind of problem. Mine seemed the least tricky.